# Solve collision className of css modules in react-create-app without eject

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, css-modules, react-css-modules

How i can solve problem of css `className` collision in `create-react-app` without eject.
I have project based on microfrontends. Components with the same names exists in independ modules. As result there are same classNames that override each other.

---

Example:

`module A` exists component `Button` with className `Button_component__1Z_hQ`

`module B` exists component `Button` with className `Button_component__1Z_hQ`

As result styles of `Button` component from `module B` override styles for `Button` component from `module A`

Comment: You tagged this [tag:react-create-app], but were you really using [tag:create-react-app]?  We are looking retag questions incorrectly tagged with [tag:react-create-app], see [What is the difference between `[create-react-app]` and `[react-create-app]`? Should the latter be aliased to the former?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419264/3744182) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest version of react you can do these:

1. Rename the CSS file to some.module.css (assuming it was some.css before)
2. Import like this:

   import styles from './some.module.css';

and styles will be an object whose keys are the ids, classes you defined in the CSS file.

So if you have a style like this:

```
.parent {
 color: red;
}
```

you would use it like

```
className={styles.parent}
```

in your JSX.

Comment: At now I using css modules. But in every render of project class names are sames.

Comment: Why should they change at every render? We generally use CSS modules so that the styles are scoped to the file where we import and use them so they are converted to random hashes and that is all we need, they don't have to generate new hashes on every render.

Comment: I have several similar application as widget, that build in general application. When one of each application was inserted in general application it crash by collision css styles for other application. So, I need to change css classNames at every render